# How to Deal JPA / JPQL with SQL Server Keyword

Tags: sql-server, jpa, keyword, jpql

My Entity class

```
@Entity
class MasterStccycode{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
   @Column(name = "CODE")
   private String code;

   @Size(max = 100)
   @Column(name = "DESC")
   private String desc;
}
```

my JPA Query
`SELECT t.code, t.desc FROM MasterStccycode t`

then I have this following exception

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>
> Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.
>
> Error Code: 156
>
> Call: SELECT CODE, DESC FROM master_stccycode 
>   Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=MasterStccycode sql="SELECT CODE, DESC FROM master_stccycode")

I know the solution is to wrap the `DESC` keyword with `[]` into `[DESC]` but how can I do this on JPA QL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC is a reserved word on most databases.  You should rename the field.

You could also quote the field, but just renaming it would be best.

```
@Column(name = "\"DESC\"")
```